# selecting multiple files modification not works with ocmod on oprencart on ver 2.0.2.0, 2.0.3.1

Tags: opencart

am already test my modifications on ver 2.0.2.0, 2.0.3.1, and find that modifications on muti file like:

```
<file path="system/{engine,library}/{action,loader,config,language}*.php">
```

not works now, am back to modifications docs, and its not update yet:
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System

i is there change on multi file modifications? or its bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same for me in 2.2.0.0.

This will not work in 2.2.0.0 (although it would in 2.1.0.x):

`<file path="catalog/file-1.php,catalog/file-2.php,catalog/file-3.php">`

But this will work in 2.2.0.0:

`<file path="catalog/file-{1,2,3}.php">`

Comment: Tested on opencart 3.0.3.2!! am so happy for this return

Comment: And you can use this (|) like 
<file path="system/engine/action.php|system/engine/loader.php|system/library/config.php">

Answer (score 1):

yes i find it, in file system/modification.xml
it was

```
  <file path="system/{engine,library}/{action,loader,config,language}*.php">
```

now you can do it like this

```
  <file path="system/engine/action.php,system/engine/loader.php,system/library/config.php,system/library/language.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

after i debug the code i found this
[error in modifications](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-nzvg31rU7bUhRVlNKenRybDQ)

it seems there big hole there..

so you can use this to downgrade modifications to ver 2.0.1.1
[modification.ocmod.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-nzvg31rU7bU5zZWFaaEc4aGc)
this mod will remove all current mods, so you need upload them again

you may need to use this ocmod, if you have error in FTP
localcopy.ocmod.xml